# Access denied for user 'Admin'@'196.250.212.121' (using password: YES) error in Amazon RDS MySQL using Springboot

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect my **springboot application running locally** to a **MySQL database on Amazon RDS**. When I run the application to use local instance of MySQL everything is fine but when I try the Amazon database I get the error

*Access denied for user 'Admin'@'196.250.211.131' (using password: YES).*

Here is my application.properties file.

```
//Local development
#Spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pharmaone
#Spring.datasource.username=root
#Spring.datasource.password=

//amazon
Spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://pharmaone.clvqfnz3ogsu.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/3306/pharmaone
Spring.datasource.username=Admin
Spring.datasource.password=mypassword
Spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= none
```

I don't understand what i am doing wrong since **I verified my username and password with MySQL workbench and I was able to connect to the remote database.**

Please help!

Comment: If that IP address in the error message is unchanged in this post, then something is wrong with your DNS lookup, that's not an AWS IP address.

Comment: Additionally, the port is specified as part of the URL, not a `:3306`.

Comment: Hey @AnonCoward it is unchanged. How doi find the correct DNS

Comment: Hey @stdunbar please explain more

Comment: You can use any number of [online lookup tools](https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php?query=pharmaone.clvqfnz3ogsu.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com&rtype=ALL&dns=google), though, really, you need to investigate why your DNS provider is returning faulty results, it will cause other problems.

Comment: Look at the pattern for localhost.  It is `localhost:3306`.  You have `pharmaone.clvqfnz3ogsu.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/3306`.  That should be a `:` character.  But, to the first comment, you're trying to connect to a RDS server in Kenya.

Comment: Okay Im kind of new to Aws. so i dont get it. How do i connect to the right server then. And why does mysql workbench connect correctly? @stdunbar

Comment: Your `Spring.datasource.url` should follow the same pattern and be `jdbc:mysql://pharmaone.clvqfnz3ogsu.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/pharmaone` with a `:` character between the hostname and port number, just like your `localhost` in local development.  You can try that but I still don't understand where the DNS lookup is failing.  I cannot lookup the hostname you've given at all.